# Feedback on Basic Website Logo

Tags: logo, critique

A friend of mine is setting up a basic English Language School and came up with his own logo combining a globe with a title and slogan.

Here is the logo:
[image]

I helped as much as I could being  developer by heart and a designer when need be. We are quite happy with it. I myself work with designers and want to improve this as much as I can myself.

I did wonder about the font combination used. We use Mistral for the green cursive looking text and Tahoma for the rest. Does anyone have a better font face combination in mind? Are the colors picked OK on this black background?

I would also appreciate general tips and feedback:

1. Choice of font for title and slogan - Do you know a font for the cursive part that would look better? Is the size OK?
2. Position Globe - Is the right side an OK choice or should it be to the left?
3. Quality Globe - I know it is still a little jagged, but do you think it will do?

Comment: "He is quite happy with it."

I'd say your work here is done...

Comment: Can you update your question to include what specifically you find unsatisfactory with the logo?  We allow critiques, but they should focus on a certain deficiency or problem that you see.  Broad "how do I improve?" questions are not a good fit.

Comment: @Farray - the asker said "Does anyone have a better font face combination in mind" and "Are the colors picked OK on this black background?". That's two very specific things... If the asker knew precisely why they felt unsatisfied, they wouldn't need to ask. This question sets up an interesting challenge, and has already got one really good answer. It's fine. It's a good addition to our low "needs some work" tally of 5 questions a day http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1924/graphic-design

Comment: @user568458 Please see http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/26/690.  Without specifying the desired result and how this design has fallen short, how are people to judge what is "better" about a different font or color choice and contribute useful answers?  Subjective questions are tricky in this regard.  Btw... A51 stats are irrelevant when considering whether a question can be improved.

Comment: Clarified the question some more. Had some great feedback already and using that for some changes,

Comment: I would say your main problem with that logo should be the watermark I see over the globe...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I usually go for a very dark grey instead of black, if possible - something like: 111111

Are you required to have the icon on the right side? Because it would flow better if it was on the left in my opinion. The logo itself though is absolutely fine for this project, but I think you need slightly better font/colour combinations to compliment it a bit better.

Try Highway Gothic Narrow for the bulk of the text and then Blackjack to replace Mistral: http://www.dafont.com/black-jack.font

*Note: Black Jack is licensed for Personal Use Only*

Here:

[image]

Just to illustrate what I'm trying to explain!

The blue is: 049cdb

The green is: 8ebd00

Which were both taken from the icon.

Comment: Thank you very much. Question is closed as it seemed to have not been clear enough, but you understood it all very well. Thanks again. Will rework logo after a chat with the owner

Comment: @rhand you can select this as an answer

Comment: You vectorized the image, with vectormagic.com? Improved the contrast, antialiasing -- seriously you have done a lot of magic here! Could you cover it a bit more detailed? Nice job, I remixed your work -- have a look, what do you think about them?

Answer (score 1):

> Choice of font for title and slogan - Do you know a font for the cursive part that would look better? Is the size OK?

I would consider changing the cursive font - your choice of Mistralis overused. Consider an option like [Calligraffitti](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Calligraffitti). You can search Google Fonts for other free cursive fonts that you can use on your desktop and on your website.

> Position Globe - Is the right side an OK choice or should it be to the left?

Position the globe on the left, and the text on the right. This will help your text balance better.  I would also increase the font size to a point where the total height of your tagline is around 80% of the height of the image.

> Quality Globe - I know it is still a little jagged, but do you think it will do?

It looks like the globe logo is a stock image - I can see the shadow of a watermark over the earth portion, which suggests your friend hasn't licensed the image. I would recommend purchasing the original image, as that will allow you to scale it to any size you need. If your friend will need to use the logo for any print materials - eg. letterhead, business cards, t-shirts - he will need to have a much larger version anyway. The cost of purchasing a single stock image is usually not very much.

Answer (score 0):

I build on top of Willow's ideas, using Gimp -- I did not add the final polishing such as antialising not to lose information, the op could add them himself. I wanted to make the initial letters somehow more apparent and I did not like the repetition in the initial logo -- also making things much more playful!

**Simple**

[image]

> **More alternatives**
>
> also created smaller logos that could be used in cards where the EPC
>   is clearly with different colors, one needs to think all little
>   details with brand etc when creating websites, better to create things
>   more consistent in the beginning! The letters symbolizes force, growth
>   and energy with some personal spin. Because the audience is children
>   and parents, I wanted to make things a bit childlike with the smile at
>   the end, making things more FuN!
>
> [image]

*P.s. Since I do not know the specific target, I left things open. You could crop things here quite easily -- "FuN!" to you as well :)*

Answer (score 0):

I agree with placing the text on the left side, and definitely less space between the text and the globe.

I would definitely increase the size of "keep growing". Maybe even so the letters overlap the "English". That would give you a sense of "growth". If this gets too dominating, tone the green colour down a little.

Also, I would keep white for the "EPS".

Apart from that? Looks good.